# the origin of "to spoil" to mean "to be eager for"

Tags: etymology

I am curious of the origin of "to spoil" meaning "to be eager for".

[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/spoil?s=t) does not even have this definition, since the Latin root of "to spoil" is "to destroy."

Merriam-Webster and Oxford English Dictionary both provide the same example "to spoil for a fight" under the meaning of "to be eager for". Is this definition a set phrase? Where did it come from?